# gdb determine stack size, conditional in command list

Tags: gdb, stack-size

Is it possible to find out the stack size (= number of frames in the stack) in a gdb script and use it as a condition in a command list? (By gdb script I mean a list of commands that can be given to gdb as "gdb --command='gdb_script' executable")

And is it possible to have conditions within command lists? I'm looking for something like this (in pseudo code):

```
break initialize.cc:41
commands
if stack.size()>4: bt 1
end
```

Thank you and kind regards, Bernd.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this with GDB 7.2, which [exposes stack frames](http://www-zeuthen.desy.de/dv/documentation/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/Frames-In-Python.html) to its embedded Python interpreter.